# Save data to Redis database

Tags: redis, nosql

```
    public class Book
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public String isbn { get; set; }
        public String title { get; set; }
        public BookPublishers publishers{ get; set; }
    }

    public class BookPublishers
    {
        public ICollection<Publisher> publisher = new List<Publisher>();

        public ICollection<Publisher> Publisher()
        {
            return this.publisher;
        }
    }

    public class Publisher
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public String phone { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }
```

I saved a book to Redis. But when i read it, the publishers property have no value. (Count = 0), other have.

I chage property publisher to : `public ICollection<Publisher> publishers { get; set; }`
I worked. 
Can someone help me. Thanks for read my question.